# Load multiple JS files with the given order using jQuery $.getScript() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, momentjs, daterangepicker

I have loaded **jQuery** first & tried to load some js files using the below method

Note: "**daterangepicker.js**" require "**moment.js**"

```
$.when(
    $.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"),
    $.getScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"),
    $.getScript("1.js"),
    $.getScript("2.js"),
    $.getScript("3.js"),
    $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        $(deferred.resolve);
    })
).done(function() {
    $('input[name=\'time\']').daterangepicker();
});
```

But i got an error

> Uncaught TypeError: moment is not a function

[image]

Then i have tried the second method.

```
$.when(
    $.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js").done(function() {
        $.getScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js").done(function() {
            alert("scripts loaded");
        });
    }),
    $.getScript("1.js"),
    $.getScript("2.js"),
    $.getScript("3.js"),
    $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        $(deferred.resolve);
    })
).done(function() {
    alert("All js files are loaded");
    $('input[name=\'time\']').daterangepicker();
});
```

This time i got

> daterangepicker is not a function

[image]

Because "**All js files are loaded"** alert is coming first & **"scripts loaded"** alert is coming second.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a new logic

```
function getScripts(scripts, callback, i) {
    i = i ? i : 0;
    $.getScript(scripts[i]).done(function() {
        ++i === scripts.length ? callback() : getScripts(scripts, callback, i);
    });
}

getScripts(
    [
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js",
        "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js",
        "1.js",
        "2.js",
        "3.js"
    ],
    function() {
        alert("all files are loaded");
        $('input[name=\'time\']').daterangepicker();
    });
```

Its working as expected.